# Publisher confirmations not working when using MassTransit, rabbitmq-message-deduplication plugin, and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Using RabbitMQ 3.8.14 and 0.5.0 of the plugin

https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication

Along with the MassTransit library in C#.

If I set up a queue to use deduplication it seems that I can only get it to work if I turn off the publisher confirms.

With publisher confirms set to true (the default and desired setting) then when a duplicate is sent I get an exception like the following

MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.MessageNotAcknowledgedException

If I set it to false then duplicates are filtered out and things work as expected.

I would like to have the deduplication and the message confirmations working if possible.

Comment: I've never used that plug-in, no idea how it works. But clearly it doesn't work with MassTransit. Disabling publisher confirmation is _NOT_ recommended as there is no indication that the message was received by the broker.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson, yes that's my view as well. I might try it with the RabbitMQ .NET client to see if I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit with publisher confirm is not supported by the plugin.

This is due to the fact the library is asking to confirm the message was published into the queue. As the message is a duplicate, it will not be published within the queue. The plugin informs the Broker of this fact and the Broker sends a negative acknowledgement back to the library.

As the Broker does not support complex notifications semantics, there is no simple way to sort this out. In other words, the Broker can only state whether the messages was published in the queue. It cannot provide any extra information in regards.

You can find a lengthy explanation of the above in this [comment](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/issues/67#issuecomment-782827895).